# C# - retrieve the selected value from a combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a comboBox with `ValueMember = ID` and `DisplayMember = Name`. I need the value that is associated with that name so I do something like this:

```
if (cboTypeOfMaterial.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string temp = cboTypeOfMaterial.SelectedValue.ToString();
                //More code here...
            }
```

Which returns the `ID` value as a string. For example - "7".

If I try :

```
if (cboTypeOfMaterial.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    string temp = cboTypeOfMaterial.DisplayMember.ToString();
                    //More code here...
                }
```

I get the string `Name` which is the key.

And what I need is to get the value of the selected element's `Name`

Comment: simply cboTypeOfMaterial.SelectedItem.ToString() should also work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SelectedValue` will return the value of the property defined in `ValueMember`, `SelectedItem` will return the entire object that is selected, if you want to get another value other than your `SelectedValue` you will have to cast as the object in your `ComboBox` then you can access your `Name` property.

```
string temp = (cboTypeOfMaterial.SelectedItem as YourObjectType).Name;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and is something new for so I'm gonna use it!

Answer (score 4):

Try to access the element via `SelectedItem` which will give you the whole object associated with that entry and then you can access the properties you need, in your case `ID`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I'm surprised no one has mentioned:

```
ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
```

which returns the text representation of the selected item (i.e. the `DisplayMember`)  and is helpful in cases involving a data bound `ComboBox`, or any `ListControl` for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create a custom class for the entries in the comboBox. This can look like:

```
public class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Display { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Display;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the selected ComboBoxItem through the following code:

```
ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)cboTypeOfMaterial.SelectedValue;
if(cbi != null)
   // Access the Property you need
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string temp = cboTypeOfMaterial.ValueMember.ToString();
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you can also use the Text property but it is not a nice solution. the better solution is what @dutzu is suggested.

```
string temp = cboTypeOfMaterial.Text;
```